# Vertical alignment of tikz matrix and tree

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, tikz-trees

I want to display a table as a tikz matrix next to a tikz tree in the same figure environment. Using the baseline option in every tikzpicture worked to align both pictures on the top for the case with two trees in the same figure environment, but not for this case! Why's that?

```
\documentclass{article}![enter image description here][1]

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{align at top/.style={baseline=(current bounding box.north)}}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
nodes={ minimum height=6mm, minimum width=2cm,align=center}
]{
\toprule
$CT$&freq\\ \midrule
$\{b,d,e\}$ &4\\ 
$\{c,e,f\}$ &3\\ 
$\{a,c\}$&4\\ 
$\{a,g\}$&4\\
$\{f\}$&4\\
$\{g\}$&4\\  
\bottomrule \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{4ex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,
        fp/.style={rectangle, draw, rounded corners=1mm,
        text centered, anchor=north},
        inact/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, rounded corners=1mm,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black!50},
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.9cm}, 
        level distance=0.8cm, growth parent anchor=south,
        transform shape]

        \node [fp] (n){$\emptyset$}
        child {[sibling distance=1.3cm]
            node [fp] (a) {$a:2$}
            child {
                node [fp] (ac) {$c:1$}
            }
            child {
                node [fp] (ab) {$b:1$}
            }
        }   
        child {[sibling distance=1.2cm]
            node[fp] (c) {$c:1$}
            child{
                node[fp] (ce) {$e:1$}
                child {
                    node[fp] (cef) {$f:1$}
                }
            }
        }
        child {
            node[fp] (e) {$e:1$}
            child {
                node[fp] (eb) {$b:1$}
                child {
                    node[fp] (ebd) {$d:1$}
                }
            }    
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{The encoding of a database (left table) and the induced tree representation of the  database (right).}
    \label{fig:tree}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It works if you add `baseline=(current bounding box.north)` to both `tikzpicture` environments.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\tikzset{align at top/.style={baseline=(current bounding box.north)}}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline = (current bounding box.north)]
\matrix (m) [matrix of nodes,
nodes={ minimum height=6mm, minimum width=2cm,align=center}
]{
\toprule
$CT$&freq\\ \midrule
$\{b,d,e\}$ &4\\
$\{c,e,f\}$ &3\\
$\{a,c\}$&4\\
$\{a,g\}$&4\\
$\{f\}$&4\\
$\{g\}$&4\\
\bottomrule \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\hspace{4ex}
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north),
        fp/.style={rectangle, draw, rounded corners=1mm,
        text centered, anchor=north},
        inact/.style={rectangle, draw=black!50, rounded corners=1mm,
        text centered, anchor=north, text=black!50},
        level 1/.style={sibling distance=1.9cm},
        level distance=0.8cm, growth parent anchor=south,
        transform shape]

        \node [fp] (n){$\emptyset$}
        child {[sibling distance=1.3cm]
            node [fp] (a) {$a:2$}
            child {
                node [fp] (ac) {$c:1$}
            }
            child {
                node [fp] (ab) {$b:1$}
            }
        }
        child {[sibling distance=1.2cm]
            node[fp] (c) {$c:1$}
            child{
                node[fp] (ce) {$e:1$}
                child {
                    node[fp] (cef) {$f:1$}
                }
            }
        }
        child {
            node[fp] (e) {$e:1$}
            child {
                node[fp] (eb) {$b:1$}
                child {
                    node[fp] (ebd) {$d:1$}
                }
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{The encoding of a database (left table) and the induced tree representation of the  database (right).}
    \label{fig:tree}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]